# Android Web App working only on some devices

Tags: php, android, html, json, web-applications

I have a webapp that controls some functions on my Raspberry but i have issues having it recognised as such from all my android devices. The website server is a Raspberry Pi 3 with Apache (all up to date).

All the IP addresses are changed with a simple 000.000.000.000 for privacy/security reasons

I can easily add the webapp to my Samsung S7 via the "add to home" option in Chrome and it works smoothly but, on all my other family Android (and iOS too) devices it does not, it's added simply as a link to the home.

This is how it's shown on my S7:
[homescreen (it gets the icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drJQ5.jpg)
[inside the webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9y6U.jpg)

This is the ***manifest.json*** code:

```
{
  "name": "Casa TAM Domotica",
  "short_name": "CasaControl",
  "theme_color": "#008eff",
  "background_color": "#085491",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "start_url": "000.000.000.000",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

This is the ***index.php*** code:

```
<?php

$c=$_GET['c'];
$r=$_GET['r'];
$g=$_GET['g'];
$b=$_GET['b'];


/* after every raspberry pi reboot it must execute pigpiod*/
$execute = shell_exec("pigpiod");

if($c == 1)
{
        $execute = shell_exec("pigpiod");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs w 12 0");
        sleep(1);
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs w 12 1");
    header('Location: 000.000.000.000');
}

if($r != "" AND $g != "" AND $b != "")
{
        $execute = shell_exec("pigpiod");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs p 22 $r");
        $execute = shell_exec("pigs p 27 $g");
    $execute = shell_exec("pigs p 17 $b");
        header('Location: 000.000.000.000');
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<head>
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
<meta name="viewport">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 1px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button0 {
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
}


.buttonblu {background-color: #008CBA;}
.buttonrosso {background-color: #f44336;}
.buttonverde {background-color: #4CAF50;}
.buttonviola {background-color: #896D93;}
.buttonarancione {background-color: #FFA500;}
.buttongiallo {background-color: #FFFF00;}
.buttonrosa {background-color: #FEB5B5;}
.buttonbianco {background-color: #FFFFFF;}


</style>
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" href="ico.ico">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Apertura cancello TAM</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function show(id) {
                if(document.getElementById) {
                        var mydiv = document.getElementById(id);
                        mydiv.style.display = (mydiv.style.display=='block'?'none':'block');
                }
        }
        </script>
        <style>
                body {
                        width:50%;
                        padding-top:5%;
                        margin:auto;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<center><a href="index.php?c=1"  class="button"><font size="100">Apertura Cancello</font></a></center>

<a href="index.php?r=0&g=140&b=186"  class="button0 buttonblu"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=244&g=67&b=54"  class="button0 buttonrosso"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=76&g=175&b=80"  class="button0 buttonverde"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=137&g=109&b=147"  class="button0 buttonviola"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=255&g=165&b=0"  class="button0 buttonarancione"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=255&g=255&b=0"  class="button0 buttongiallo"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=254&g=181&b=181"  class="button0 buttonrosa"></a>
<a href="index.php?r=155&g=155&b=155"  class="button0 buttonbianco"></a>
</p>
<IFRAME src="000.000.000.000/cam_pic_new.php" align="center" width="1080" height="810" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 marginheight="0px"</IFRAME>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the manifest.json wasn't always read by the system, i added more instances of

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

to fix the problem